# MetaData Extractor Topaz

Tags: metadata-extractor

I am trying to write code to look through my photos to see which photos have been processed by various tools. Do you have any plans to extract metadata left by Topaz Labs AI Sharpen, DeNoise, Gigapixel, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that Metadata Extractor already pulls out metadata added by those software applications. There are several standard tags into which it may add data.

If those programs produce custom metadata, then we can potentially add support for them to the library. At the minimum we would need some sample images (the image itself is not important, and must be licensed so that we can share it publicly).